# How to fetch method call using a custom migration fixer in lib2to3?

Tags: python, migration

I am trying to create a custom migration fixer for lib2to3. The idea of the fixer is to fetch specific constructions, such as:

```
a.b()
```

We have tried using a script called `find_pattern.py`, but with no luck so far. The output is the following:

```
power< 'a' trailer< '.' 'b' > trailer< '(' ')' > >
```

But unfortunately, as you might have guessed - this doesn't work. What Pattern for the `BaseFix` should we use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the pattern that needs to be prepared.

```
PATTERN = '''
    power< head=any+
     trailer< '.' method=any >
     parens=trailer< '(' tail=[argument | arglist] ')'>

    >
'''
```